# Create OnclickListener for specific view in recyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, adapter

*I am a beginner in stack-overflow and this is my first question,that i cant solve that. so before every thing excuse me if I don't know more about this site.*

**The question is:**

I want click on a specific view of one item of recyclerView adapter from activity and not from own adapter, some thing like implement on-click from adapter to activity that called this adapter.

*thanks for reading this unclear text :)*

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) have a look around, and read through the [HELP center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), then read [How to Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and provide a [MCVE : Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If people around can easily read and understand what you mean, or what the problem is, they'll be more likely willing to help :)

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly you can obtain your goal by using an interface. 
Your adapter should contain an instance of a listener for your click event.

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

    OnAdapterClickListener onAdapterClickListener;

    public MyAdapter(OnAdapterClickListener onAdapterClickListener) {
        this.onAdapterClickListener = onAdapterClickListener;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(onAdapterClickListener != null) {
                    onAdapterClickListener.onViewClicked(view);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The interface should be something like this:

```
public interface OnAdapterClickListener {

    void onViewClicked(View view);
}
```

And finally your activity has to implement the interface:

```
public class MainActivity implements OnAdapterClickListener {

    private MyAdapter myAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        myAdapter = new MyAdapter(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewClicked(View view) {

    }
}
```

Now you can implement your OnClickListener in your Activity.